# Module placed in main area and displaying article images? Is that allowed?

Tags: component, module

**Edit: ____________________________________________________________________**

*To clarify this. It’s not about how to code it. But a question about which to choose. Module or Component?*
**_________________________________________________________________________**

I am new to Joomla and need to develop a custom part of a site.

The custom part should be located in the main area.

I know how to develop modules and would prefer to do it this way. But I also know that a module should be used for content in the sidebar and you should use a component for the main area.

The custom part is a thing that loads and shows text rows from a table I've created in the database. It also needs the ability to edit and save the texts. And lastly, it needs to display the intro image of specific articles.

The custom part doesn't need to have the ability to be edited in any way from the admin side. It only needs to have the part that is visible on the front end.

Therefor the question is: Can I use a module for this?

Comment: There is no rule that says modules should be used somewhere specifically. Since your question is Can I use a module for this? I would say a quick answer is yes - probably you can. You actually can use any means of workable code that fetches data from the database and display them in the html. -----Note that the information given in your question is pretty much vague - making the whole topic too broad or your question as unclear. As it stands now, it is hard to get an objective answer. So consider to update your question with more details, or it might get flagged for closure.------

Comment: @JonasBjon what have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?  Please show us some code.

Comment: @mickmackusa I haven’t started on this. I want to be sure it’s okay to use a module for this :)

Comment: Ok.  Have a crack at it.  This question, as previously commented by a moderator, is poorly suited to Q&A.  Once you've had a go, if you have isolated concerns or issues please post a question.  Perhaps take down this question for now so as to avoid encouraging brief / vague / low value answers.

Comment: @mickmackusa I may not have been clear. To clarify things, It’s not a question about how to code this. The question is if I should use a component or a module for this project. As I’m new to Joomla, I don’t know what to choose and want to avoid rewriting the code because of choosing the module solution

Comment: I am new to Joomla too and have only written custom modules up to this point, but your task seems suited to a module so I can't see any reason not to charge forward with a module.

Comment: @mickmackusa Okay, I’ll give it a shot with the module then. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: If you're going to use it to add table records, it should be a component.

Comment: @Sharky Okay, good to know. But why? I mean I have made a module before that added table records

Comment: @FFrewin Is this question Off-topic: opinion-based? Or can this question be answered objectively?  I don't know enough to make this distinction.

Comment: @JonasB It can be done but it's not the correct way of doing things. Data should be submitted through forms and handled by component's model/controller. By doing this in the module alone you would need to write a lot of custom code or you'd be missing out on important features such as data validation. Look at Joomla's core modules for examples. Banners are displayed in the module but they are managed by component and clicking on them takes you to through component. Login data in `mod_login` is sent to `com_users` controller, etc.

Comment: @Sharky Thank you! This is what I was looking for and I think it´s a great answer. Can you make it as an answer so I can accept it? :)

Comment: @Sharky it seems that you have a sufficient understanding to offer a thoughtful answer and resolve this page.  Please post your comments (and any other relevant info) as an answer.